# Can you "force" Apache to serve up an "index of" page (when that's not been disabled) even if the default file exists?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I'm trying to get some old files off of a website.  Not maliciously, and if I fail I'll just contact the owner of the site, but this is more fun.

```
/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/
```

works fine, and presents me with an "index of" page full of images and PDFs etc.

```
/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/
```

doesn't work though, because there's a default file (index.php) present in it.

Is it possible to somehow "bypass" that default file from my (user) end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [`mod_autoindex`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html) will not generate an autoindex in the presence of the appropriate [`DirectoryIndex`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) file.